# How to Force y-axis forceNiceScale to work when we have small range?

Tags: angular, apexcharts

I'm working with Apexcharts for an angular project and I want my barchart to start from zero. I tried this this method:

```
   yaxis: {
    forceNiceScale: true,
   
  }
```

But it only works when I have larger range. How should I fix this ?

Comment: Could you please add completed component code?

Comment: @PramodKharade you can find it down below

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to draw that chart :

```
CreateChartOptions(keyslist: any, valueslist: any) {
    return {
      series: [
        {
          name: "pl %",
          data: valueslist
        }
      ],
    
      
      chart: {
        type: "bar",
        height: 300,
        fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
        toolbar: {
          show: true,
          offsetX: -17,
          offsetY: -30,
          autoSelected: 'pan',
        
          tools: {
            download: true,
            zoom: true
          },
        },
        events: {
       
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          horizontal: false,
          columnWidth: this.columnWidth,
          borderRadius: 5,
          colors: {
            ranges: [{
              from: -100,
              to: -0,
              color: '#FAE0E4'
            },
            {
              from: 0,
              to: 100,
              color: '#BDE4A7'
            }]
          },

        }
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      xaxis: {
        tickPlacement: 'on',
        categories: keyslist,
        min: this.minimumpipsBarsValue,
        max: valueslist.length
      },
      yaxis: {
        forceNiceScale: true,
       
      }
      ,
 
    

    }
  }
```